# AirBnB's Enzyme test (for React Component) returning SyntaxError

Tags: reactjs, npm, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have an Enzyme test that is straight out of a tutorial somewhere:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('<Keypad />', () => {

    it('should render children when passed in', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
          <MyComponent>
            <div className="unique" />
          </MyComponent>
        );
        expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="unique" />)).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

I keep getting a syntax error, unexpected token:

```
SyntaxError: test.js: Unexpected token     (9:4)
   7 |  it('should render children when passed in', () => {
   8 |          const wrapper = mount(
>  9 |            <MyComponent>
     |            ^
  10 |              <div className="unique" />
  11 |            </MyComponent>
  12 |          );
```

Any ideas? I have all of these modules installed, and configured in my package.json file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
   },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "helmet": "^2.1.0",
    "if-env": "^1.0.0",
    "object.assign": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "winston": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

I am running npm test on Windows:

```
"test": "mocha src/home/test.js -c --compilers js:babel-register --recursive",
```

*****EDIT******

This is my component file:

```
// Library / Framework imports
import React, { Component } from 'react'

/*
 * @class Home
 * @description Display the home page React Component
 */
 export default class Home extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <section>
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
                <p>This is the home page</p>
            </section>
        )
     }
 }
```

This is my test file:

```
// Library / Framework imports
import React from 'react'
import { mount, render, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import Home from './Home.jsx'

describe('<Home />', () => {

    it('should render children when passed in', () => {

        const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
        console.log(wrapper)
    })
})
```

The error is:

```
SyntaxError: D:/home/test.js: Unexpected token (12:26)
  10 |
  11 |          // console.log(SubmitButton)
> 12 |          const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
     |                                  ^
  13 |          console.log(wrapper)
  14 |
  15 |          // expect(<SubmitButton />).contains()).to.equal(true)
```

I tried shallow, render and mount. What am I missing here? I am using the latest React 15 version. All of the latest modules in fact - just did an npm install. I must have missed a fundamental understanding of how to use this library. Please help!

Comment: just checking, but whats MyComponent? you mean Keypad?

Comment: you need to use Keypad, then...

Comment: Same issue as before. Why should it matter what the name of the Component is?

Comment: I did get the mocha enzyme example to work, but it has lots of old module versions and also a setup.js file which is not mentioned in the docs

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes! I forgot to use PhantomJS....doh! Needs to run in a browser, of course! I was running just as a stand alone unit test

Answer (score 0):

`<MyComponent>` is just an example, you need to use `<Keypad/>` in mount

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <Keypad>
    <div className="unique" />
  </Keypad>
);
```

Comment: Same issue as before. Why should it matter what the name of the Component is?

Comment: because there is no such thing as MyComponent, thats just an example, that parts obvious, this is likely a parsing error, you need to follow the directions about setting up - check this out: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-mocha

Comment: I have updated my code to show the error - using my actual component. What am I missing please? I read the docs and feel like this should work, but I must be misunderstanding a fundamental piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with [not setting adapter config for enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367184/react-enzyme-testing-library)

simply you should run code below in root directory of your app :

`npm i --save-dev enzyme-adapter-react-16`

then add these lines to your test:

```
  import Enzyme, {configure, shallow} from 'enzyme';
  import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

  Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

  describe(
    //what ever that was 
  );
```

But it's another chance to addressed Home component to the wrong place, check it first, then test the solution that I mentioned earlier.